# Boot to specific OS depending on power-on button

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, hardware

I have both Ubuntu and Windows installed on my computer.

On my previous Ubuntu install turning the computer on by pressing the *normal* power-on button would boot the system directly to Ubuntu (grub_timeout was set to 0).

Turning the computer on pressing the Assist button would boot directly to Windows.

[image]

After removing and reinstalling Ubuntu the Assist button no longer boots to Windows.
Where and how can I configure the system to boot a specific OS depending on the power-on button?

Comment: I would be happy to see and accept a more general answer to question than the one I provided.

Comment: I try to find this question but always forget, because I don't know what the correct term, I just know is as 'secondary power button'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Not exactly sure how so my instructions will be a bit fuzzy.

I was trying to follow GRUB's [instructions on enabling vendor power-on keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Vendor-power_002don-keys.html#Vendor-power_002don-keys).

After unsuccessfully getting a difference :

```
diff normal_button.txt normal_vendor.txt
```

between (on normal boot) :

```
sudo modprobe nvram
sudo cat /dev/nvram | xxd > normal_button.txt
```

and (on vendor button boot)

```
sudo modprobe nvram
sudo cat /dev/nvram | xxd > normal_vendor.txt
```

This sentence in the instructions caught my eye :

> To take full advantage of this function, install GRUB into the MBR

Instead of reinstalling Grub on the MBR, I changed the MBR. I opened GParted and changed the **boot flag** from my Windows partition to my Ubuntu partition. For an unknown reason this was enough to make it work

Comment: Thanks for the information, Based on my experience, is not work on BIOS boot mode, and I got diff result after booting in UEFI mode. I will try to make this button work and will add the answer to.

Comment: What kind of computer has an "assist" button or any other than the power button that can be used to boot a different OS? I'm trying to find that since long ago...